# Import csv via fread skipping first line and header on second line

Tags: r, import, data.table

Trying to import a csv using `fread` from the `data.table` package. Need to skip the first two lines. The first line has gibberish. The second line has the headers. The following `read.csv` code does what I need:

```
data <- read.csv(file="C:/1.csv", skip=1, header=TRUE)
```

I would like to know how to achieve the same with `fread`. Thank you.

Comment: have you looked at/tried the `skip` and `header` arguments to `fread` ... ???

Comment: `fread` works. `data <- fread('C:/1.csv', skip = 1, header = T)`. Can you give us a reproducible example?

Comment: The data.table package also has outstanding documentation.

Comment: Found the documentation part on `skip` argument quite convoluted. Hence my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fread` is intended to be similar to `read.table`, `read.csv`, etc. so

```
data <- fread("C:/1.csv", skip=1, header=T)
```

will work.